# wordpress - get all terms associated with a taxonomy slug

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I have a jobs **page** which is a standard page. I also have a custom post type setup as **jobs**. There is also a taxonomy for jobs called **Job Categories** which I have added a test one call **test-category**.

What I want to do is on the jobs **page**, get all categories that are associated with any **jobs** post type (list as a header) and then under list the titles of those posts.

What I am struggling to achieve is to get all job categories associated with with the post type jobs.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this part of the WordPress Codex's page on the wp_list_categories() function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy

You should be able to list everything in the Job Categories taxonomy by using something like this:

```
<?php

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'job_categories',
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'hierarchical' => 1
);

wp_list_categories($args);

?>
```